# Kernel module for create hostapd on android things, it is supported?

Tags: android, android-wifi, kernel-module, hotspot, android-kernel

Hello I am trying to create an access point on [android things for raspberry pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/download.html), the hostapd configuration:

```
cat > data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf << EOF
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/hostapd
ssid=myid
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
EOF
```

I have the following errors on logcat when call `/system/bin/hostapd -e /data/misc/wifi/entropy.bin /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf`

E hostapd : Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported on transport endpoint)

I hostapd : rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device

W hostapd : wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver

If I write `lsmod` I Have the following error: lsmod: No file /proc/modules: No such file or directory

So what is the correct `driver=` value to create the ap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also try this using java code for create wifi hotspot but it does not allow an y device to connect that wifi network